# compile external class in php

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm learning about an object oriented approach to design web back-end using php.
I am a complete beginner in php OOP.
So, I was having a problem getting a external file containing a php class to run in another file.
Here's my code:

```
A.php

<?php
class A
{
    public function getProperty()
    {
        echo "Good job sir, You've won a free House!";
    }
}
?>

B.php
<?php
include("A.php");

class B
{
$a= new A();

$a->getProperty();

}
?>
```

I get an internal server error when running B.php,
Both files are under same directory.

Comment: That's because `B` is all around syntactically incorrect. Enable error_reporting/display.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but knowing Java, I suspect the problem is that the code is enclosed in `class B {` and `}`. It should be outside the class.

Comment: ^ You don't put procedural code straight in a class. You can put it straight in a PHP file.  But if you put it in a class, it must go in a function.

Comment: Check example 2 on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//Try this it should work

```
include('A.php');

class B
{
   public function test(){
        $a= new A();
        $a->getProperty();
   }

}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

//OUTPUT
Good job sir, You've won a free House!

Comment: your solution works, thanks! But I had a look at php's manual and came across a code like this: A::getProperty(); without using the include() function. Is there a difference? or they interchangeable?

Comment: A::getProperty() is usually used to access static methods and fields while
$a->getProperty() is usually used to access non-static methods via the object or class instance similar to that in java